# NSPredicate with (match OR match) AND match

Tags: objective-c, nspredicate

I want a predicate to this:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(self isKindOfClass: %@ || self isKindOfClass: %@) AND isActive == YES", [TestClass1 class], [TestClass2 class]];
```

But the () do not work as I thought they would as it does in an if stmt:

```
if ((condition1 || condition2) && otherCondition) {
}
```

That if stmt will be true if either 'condition1' or 'condition2' is true plus 'otherCondition' is true.

Can I do that with a `NSPredicate`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(isActive == YES AND (class == %@ OR class == %@))", [TestClass1 class], [TestClass2 class]];
```